# Nuxtjs || Why is my vendors/app.js over 10mb big?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am currently learning nuxtjs and therefore created a small application based on create-nuxt-app.
Now I had a look at the developer console and saw, that one of my files has 10.5mb.
That can not be normal, can it?

[image]

Anything I am missing there? Why is it so big?

Best Regards

Martin

Comment: you are in development mode, in prod is much smaller [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-dev/)

Comment: If that doesn't work, try analyze your bundle. To turn on analyzer, add `analyze: true` under `build` property on `nuxt.config.js`, then run `npm run generate`